# EF6 proxy's reference is sometimes null when entity's IValidatableObject.Validate method is called

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, nullreferenceexception

An EF6 proxy has a reference that is sometimes null when my entity's `IValidatableObject.Validate` method is called by the DbContext's `SaveChangesAsync` method.

Running the same exact code multiple times results in different behavior. If I check my stock's `Sku` property (i.e. `stock.Sku == null`) outside of the `Validate` method it always returns a materialized entity. If I do not do that and only check `this.Sku` within the `Validate` method then `this.Sku` will *sometimes* be null for the exact same entity. And by "exact same entity" I mean that I am testing the one stock multiple times that has the same `Id` and `SkuId` across all test runs. I'm not creating a new stock here or changing the value of its `SkuId` property. The one thing I am doing is calling the stock's `ChangeQuantity` method and then saving changes.

My best guess at this point is that once save changes is called all entity and reference materialization is frozen. If the `Sku` property has not already been accessed at least once then it will be null and remain null when the DB context's save changes code calls my object's `Validate` method.

**My questions are: Why is this happening and why can't I depend on that property being available to be lazy loaded at anytime?**

```
public abstract class StockBase : RecordBase
{
    // Snipped //

    [Required, Display(Name = "SKU")]
    public Guid SkuId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "SKU")]
    public virtual Sku Sku { get; protected set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; private set; }

    [DataType("StockActions")]
    public virtual ICollection<StockAction> Actions { get; private set; }

    public void ChangeQuantity(DateTime logged, Guid loggedById, int changeInQuantity, string notes = null)
    {
        TrackChange(logged, loggedById);
        Quantity += changeInQuantity;
        Actions.Add(new StockAction(logged, loggedById, changeInQuantity));
    }
}

public class StandardStock : StockBase, IValidatableObject
{
    // Snipped //

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // Right here is where `this.Sku` is sometimes null!
        if (Sku.IsExpiringStock)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Standard stock must have a non-expiring SKU.");
        }

        yield break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, lazy loading is disabled during validation when performed through Entity Framework.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959#Considerations

Comment: Aha! It is documented and by design. Thank you for taking the time to look it up. I totally thought this might be an undocumented buggaroo.

Comment: You're welcome! I had looked this up in the past when implementing validation, so I happened to know where it was.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using lazy loading to populate the Sku object.  When you test the Sku property manually, you are forcing the lazy loading to run, and the value gets materialised.  If you're already doing something with the context at the time you're expecting it to be loaded, or the context has been disposed, then it will remain as null.

If you always need to populate this property, consider explicitly loading it when you load the entity.  This will stop your lazy loading problem, and also eliminate a trip to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the response Richard and that is the way to work around it. The thing is though that I understand that I could force the load or use .Include(...) when querying, and my triggering a lazy load earlier in the code essentially does that. It's just that I assumed that I could depend on that property being available for lazy loading at **anytime** is apparently invalid. The fact that it doesn't seem to be is a surprise to me and I would like to know why, not what to do to work around it.